# Why is the hover behavior unintuitive in case of ul and li?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wanted to highlight each menu item with red color while hovering over it. So with my intuition I did `.menu ul li: hover{...}`.

**Doubt 1:** But this made only the `li` text background change the color and not the padding part of the `li`. Why isn't the `padding` change the color?Isn't the `padding` also a part of `li` element?

**Doubt 2:** I achieved the expected behavior by doing `.menu ul :hover` as shown in the below code. But this is against my intuition. Doesn't it say the entire `ul` should change the background color while hovering on it, so that the entire menu items will be highlighted?

**The Code:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px ;
  width: 100px ;
  top:10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.menu ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right:40px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
}
.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  display: inline;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
.menu ul :hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo_new1.png" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use a space between `ul`/`li` and `:hover`, because the sub-items would be formatted for hovering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are not hovering the `ul` because you have a space between the `ul` and `:hover` so it is adding `background:red` to  all children elements of `ul`( which are `li`) when hovered. That's why you think you it is working with `ul`,

This is the real output of your code

```css
.menu ul *:hover {background:red}
```

The `:hover` it will affect the `padding` **if** that element has `padding` if not, it won't add `padding`, so if you want to  have `padding` you have to `:hover` the `li`

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.menu ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo_new1.png" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Activities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```